# Adding bibiographic references to the document class "slides."

Tags: bibliographies, slideshow

I want to add bibliography to a simple slide class, such as:

```
\documentclass[landscape,leqn]{slides}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\begin{document}
This slide contains a citation: \cite{knuth1984texbook}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The content of references.bib is the following one:

```
@book{knuth1984texbook,
 author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
 title = {The \TeX book},
 publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
 year = {1984},
}
```

I can compile the document and I get the following slide:

---

---

This slide contains a citation: [1].

*References

[1] Donald E. Knuth. The TEXbook. Addison-Wesley, 1984.

---

---

I also get the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence.
\\blx@head@bibliography [#1]->\section 
      *{#1}\@mkboth {\abx@MakeMarkcase {#1}...
```

It seems that the title for the references section is not produced appropriately (see "*references" at the beginning of the references). Is this problem caused because the slides document class does not define the \section command for use in the bibliography? Is there a way to fix this (preferably not using Beamer)?